# Get the wrong date in php with a virtual machine

Tags: php, date, datetime, php-5.3, php-5.4

I installed a virtual machine with php, mysql, apache2.

Now when I write in the terminal : `date` I get : `Thu Dec 06:55:25 EET 2016`.

When I try to get the now date in php,

I write : `error_log(print_r(new \DateTime('now'),true), 3, "/tmp/error.log");`
And I get :

```
DateTime Object
(
  [date] => 2016-12-01 06:56:33
  [timezone_type] => 3
  [timezone] => Europe/Bucharest
)
```

But now the hour is : `17:06`.

How can resolve this ? Please help me and sorry for my english.

Comment: It looks like the system and PHP dates are in sync, but incorrect. You need to fix the date in your OS.

Comment: @aynber, How to fix that ? Exist a way ?

Comment: I'm fond of `sudo ntpdate pool.ntp.org`, if the virtual machine is using linux.

Comment: Works................

Answer (score -1):

> - Make sure that you're settng timezones in correct **php.ini** file
> - Make sure your system timings are correct first.

You can set default timezone in PHP like this:

- Open your **php.ini** file
- Add the following line of code to top of your *php.ini* file

  `date.timezone = "Your Timezone Here"`
- Once you've saved the changes, restart your apache and php services.
- You get it running right from now on.

> See more about [PHP Timezone](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Exist a solution ?

Comment: I didn't get you!!